DNS Server for Redirecting IP with Port?
I have some docker containers; although I want to access those containers instead of IP:[port] I want to access by means of a custom domain name which I have how do I set this up ?
Although those containers some require a password, I don't want a password when accessed on the local network, when accessed outside the local network, I want the password to be asked as it is for those containers ?
I'm using a Synology Router and in SRM for DNS server I'm first asked to pick a zone; there are Master, Slave; forwarding and import. Which must I pick ?

Welcome to SuperUser. SuperUser's format really only works if you ask a single question per Question post, so please edit your Question post to focus it on a single question. But by the way, DNS doesn't really know about port numbers, only hostnames.

How can I accomplish what I want ?

That's a good question. I'd say maybe delete this Question post, then create a new Question post, asking something like "How to reach different Docker containers behind a NAT, without specifying port numbers?". In that Question post, be specific about which protocols you care about; there may be easier answers if this is all about HTTP so you can use HTTP redirects or reverse proxy. Solutions might be more difficult to find if you care about a mix of different protocols like HTTP, FTP, SSH, RDP, IMAP, SMTP, etc.

Can I ask you an offtopic question in this post before deleting ?

Sure, go ahead.

I find Stack Overflow etc very difficult to ask questions. I ask questions in a way that even when explained in as much detail as I can, sometimes it's not good enough. I've experienced this in the past.
How do I get a good question, I know many questions have been asked, sometimes you don't understand the answer. You decide to ask the question again; whether right or wrong under Stack way of question asking. What makes it or people scream that they don't understand the question or like the question ?

Oh, man, I remember that feeling when I started. You're not alone. The key thing to know is the Stack Exchange format only wants questions that can have a solid answer that can be officially "accepted" (marked as correct / most helpful), and ideally questions someone else might want the answer to, so it becomes the top hit on Google. So nothing asking for opinions, discussions, stuff that's too specific to one person's weird setup, nothing that goes out of date too quickly. Each SE site has guidelines for what kinds of questions work or don't work on that site. Read it before asking. 1/

There are other sites for the kinds of questions that don't fit the SE format. So use a site like Reddit for those other kinds of questions. A well-known open source software contributor and technical book author named Eric S. Raymond (ESR) wrote a great How-To on asking technical questions to tech nerds (whom he calls "hackers", but not in the infosec-breaking sense), in ways that get good answers fast without annoying people. Read How To Ask Questions The Smart Way and keep its advice in mind, here on SE sites or elsewhere. 2/2

BTW, one problem with your original question, besides not being a single question, was that it was an XY Problem. Your real problem, X, it seems to me, was getting to different Docker containers behind a NAT without specifying port numbers. But instead of asking X, you headed down a dead-end path toward a solution, but didn't know it was a dead-end, so you asked how to solve the dead-end problem, Y, (how to use DNS to respond to hostname lookups with responses that include port numbers, which DNS doesn't do). Always ask the X question, not the Y question.

This sounds more like a phycological way to ask questions, rather then just asking questions. I'm going to read those documents. And although this question has gone off-topic I'll keep it alive for a bit just to fire you two or three more questions after reading if required.

Forums are great for open discussion, wide ranging commentary, asides, opinion, etc. They have their place, and because of their more open format they can also accept a wider range of questions. Superuser has risen above many of the other information sources online largely because it has higher standards. This can be very frustrating for people who aren't aware of the differences, but the pay-off is that the quality of information you CAN get here could be far better. In other words, you'll get out what you put in. Read the Help section, do a LOT of research and self effort, and show all that.

My question asking is different to that of how SuperUser \ StackOverflow is designed for questions to be asked.
I want to ask the questions that work for this site, but obviously even reading the posted sites, it will take a bit of time. Whether the moderators on this site excuse some bumps in my questions or not, is up to them.
Forums are great for open discussions but the answers you sometimes get are not even sometimes close to the answer you are looking for, that or the answer is just like a mixed up response. And you have to ask questions for someone answer.
